# any tips how to do something like that in ios

Tags: ios

I want to create something like this , it will be the main page of my ipad app , it's something like tab in chrome web browser

[image]

I am not sure how to start by

also I want to create a custome table with 3 columns , headers and title like this

[image]

Any idea how to achieve that please

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I think you want something like this... So this is `BHTabbarDemo`.
You can download this project from https://github.com/fictorial/BHTabBar

 This is hint may be it is not exactly same as what you want but it would help you.

Have nice coding!